Visual Studio 2022 : error 1296 Hardware 'Test_(01)' does not have an associated service using install section 'A9_GBD'
I upgraded my Visual Studio from 2017 to 2022, and also the SDK and WDK do the brand release. In the past with older releases I have no issue with V3 printer INF File. Now I always get an error with code 1296

Hardware 'Test_(01)' does not have an associated service using install section 'A9_GBD'

I found that the reason is by the new "Primitive Drivers" concept in Windows 10 and 11. I am searching for a solution or sample how it looks correctly with new concept, but I don't find anything.
Here is my code who get this error 1296. Does somebody have an idea what is wrong here ?
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=%Test GmbH%
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
DriverVer=07/05/2024,1.8.6-01
CatalogFile=Testprinting.cat
PnpLockdown=1

;
; Manufacturer section.
;

[Manufacturer]
%Test GmbH% =   Test, NTx86, NTia64

; Model Specifications Section
;
[Test.NTx86]
"Test_(01)"         = A9_GBD, Test_A9_GBD

[Test.NTia64]
"Test_(01)"         = A9_GBD, Test_A9_GBD

;
; Installer section(s) referenced above.
;

[A9_GBD]
CopyFiles=@A9_GBD.Dll,@A9_GBD.GPD
DataSection=UNIDRV_BIDI_DATA
DataFile=A9_GBD.GPD
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV_BIDI.OEM


[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000

[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1 = %location%,,,
2 = %location%,,,x86

[SourceDisksNames.ia64]
1 = %location%,,,
2 = %location%,,,x64

[SourceDisksFiles.ia64]
A9_GBD.Dll = 2
A9_GBD.GPD = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
A9_GBD.Dll = 2
A9_GBD.GPD = 1

[Strings]
PrinterClassName="Printer"
Test GmbH="Test GmbH"
location="Installation Source Media"
VERSION="1.8.6-01"


Various possible solutions are given in the inf validation page for code 1296, have you checked them?

Thank you  for your tip Neitsa. It helps me farther. The  reason for this error was two missing lines: [A9_GBD.Services]
AddService= ,0x00000002
